# Exception in Tkinter callback latitude

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
import phonenumbers
from phonenumbers import carrier
from phonenumbers import geocoder
from phonenumbers import timezone
from timezonefinder import TimezoneFinder
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
from datetime import datetime

import pytz

root=Tk()
root.title('Phone Number Traker')
root.geometry('365x584+400+100')
root.resizable(False,False)

def track():
    inserisci_numero=entry.get()
    number=phonenumbers.parse(inserisci_numero)

    locate=geocoder.description_for_number(number,"IT")
    country.config(text=locate)
    operator=carrier.name_for_number (number,"it")
    sim.config (text=operator)

    time = timezone.time_zones_for_number(number)
    zona.config(text=time)

    geolocator= Nominatim(user_agent="geopiExercises")
    location= geolocator.geocode(locate)
    lng = location.longitude
    lat = location.latitude
    longitude.config(text=lng)
    latitude.config(text=lat)

    obj= TimezoneFinder()
    result=obj.timezone_at(lng=location.longitude,lat=location.latitude)

    home=pytz.timezone(result)
    local_time= datetime.now(home)
    current_time=local_time.strftime ("%I:%M:%p")
    clock.config(text=current_time)



logo=PhotoImage(file="logo image.png")
Label(root,image=logo).place(x=240,y=70)

Heading = Label(root,text ="Traccia",font=("arial",15,"bold"))
Heading.place(x=90,y=110)

Entry_back= PhotoImage(file="search png.png")
Label (root,image=Entry_back).place(x=20,y=190)

entry=StringVar()
inserisci_numero = Entry(root,textvariable=entry,width=17,bd=0,font=
("arial",20),justify="center")
inserisci_numero.place(x=50,y=220)

Serach_image =PhotoImage(file="search.png")
search =Button(image=Serach_image,borderwidth=0,cursor="hand2",bd=0,font=("arial",16),command=
track)
search.place(x=35,y=300)

Box=PhotoImage(file="bottom png.png")
Label(root,image=Box).place(x=-2,y=355)

country=Label(root,text = "Country: ",bg="#57adff",fg="black",font=("arial",10,"bold"))
country.place(x=50,y=400)

sim=Label(root,text = "SIM: ",bg="#57adff",fg="black",font=("arial",10,"bold"))
sim.place(x=200,y=400)

zona=Label(root,text = "Zona: ",bg="#57adff",fg="black",font=("arial",10,"bold"))
zona.place(x=50,y=450)

clock=Label(root,text = "Phone Time: ",bg="#57adff",fg="black",font=("arial",10,"bold"))
clock.place(x=200,y=450)

    longitude=Label(root,text = "Longitudine: ",bg="#57adff",fg="black",font=("arial",10,"bold"))

longitude.place(x=50,y=500)

latitude=Label(root,text = "Latitudine: ",bg="#57adff",fg="black",font=("arial",10,"bold"))
latitude.place(x=200,y=500)


root.mainloop()
```

when I start the application I can't see on the screen, neither the
country nor the position. what did i do wrong? using pytnon 3.10. I
am going crazy

Comment: I recommend trying to reduce the code down to a [mcve]. The question seems to be about laying out the widgets, so we probably don't need the phonenumbers module or some of the functions. Also, if you're getting an exception, please include the actual exception in your question.

Comment: Add this track() after root.mainloop()

Comment: You need to call `track()` after you have input something into the `Entry` widget, like by clicking a button.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: i can't solve it, thanks everyone